# "Timed out starting Power-Off" 30 minutes after "Reached target Shutdown", computer takes 30 minutes to power off

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shutdown

When I shut down my computer running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, it takes seconds to reach the final `Reached target Shutdown` message as shown on the console.  However, after this message has been shown, it takes a long time to physically switch off.  From `journalctl`, I observe that 90 seconds after `Reached target Shutdown`, `systemd` shows `dev-sda5.swap: Deactivation timed out`, and exactly 30 minutes after `Reached target Shutdown` (28:30 after the swap deactivation error), it shows `Timed out starting Power-Off` and `Forcibly powering off as result of failure`, immediately before finally switching off.  The 30-minute timeout only seems to occur if the computer has been on for a while (hours).  If the computer has only been on for a short time (less than an hour), it usually shuts down quickly.

Final lines of `journalctl` for a case where it **does** shut down quickly:

```
dec 04 09:23:54 sjisjka systemd[1]: dev-.bootchart-proc.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
dec 04 09:23:54 sjisjka systemd[1]: Failed unmounting /dev/.bootchart/proc.
dec 04 09:23:54 sjisjka systemd[1]: Unmounted /run/user/129.
dec 04 09:23:54 sjisjka systemd[1]: Unmounted /run/user/1000.
dec 04 09:23:54 sjisjka systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
dec 04 09:23:54 sjisjka systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
dec 04 09:23:54 sjisjka systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
dec 04 09:23:54 sjisjka systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
dec 04 09:23:57 sjisjka systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/a092fe32-c536-4c0c-bd2e-416f606b2c33.
dec 04 09:23:57 sjisjka systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.5-ata-1-part5.
dec 04 09:23:57 sjisjka systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5002538d40d0e7c8-part5.
dec 04 09:23:57 sjisjka systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_500GB_S2RBNX0H448728M-part5.
dec 04 09:23:57 sjisjka systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/sda5.
dec 04 09:23:57 sjisjka systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
dec 04 09:23:57 sjisjka systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
dec 04 09:23:57 sjisjka systemd[1]: Starting Power-Off...
dec 04 09:23:57 sjisjka systemd-udevd[13082]: failed to execute '/lib/udev/socket:@/org/freedesktop/hal/udev_event' 'socket:@/org/freedesktop/hal/udev_event': No such file or directory
dec 04 09:23:57 sjisjka systemd-udevd[13079]: Process 'socket:@/org/freedesktop/hal/udev_event' failed with exit code 2.
dec 04 09:23:57 sjisjka systemd[1]: Shutting down.
dec 04 09:23:57 sjisjka systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
dec 04 09:23:57 sjisjka systemd-journald[304]: Journal stopped
-- Reboot --
```

Final lines of a case where it **does not** shut down quickly:

```
dec 05 23:55:06 sjisjka systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: ebtables ruleset management.
dec 05 23:55:06 sjisjka systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems.
dec 05 23:55:06 sjisjka systemd[1]: Unmounting /dev/.bootchart/proc...
dec 05 23:55:06 sjisjka systemd[1]: Unmounting /run/user/129...
dec 05 23:55:06 sjisjka systemd[1]: Unmounted /dev/.bootchart/proc.
dec 05 23:55:06 sjisjka systemd[1]: Unmounted /run/user/129.
dec 05 23:55:06 sjisjka systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
dec 05 23:55:06 sjisjka systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
dec 05 23:55:06 sjisjka systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
dec 05 23:55:06 sjisjka systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
dec 05 23:56:36 sjisjka systemd[1]: dev-sda5.swap: Deactivation timed out. Stopping.
dec 05 23:56:36 sjisjka systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/sda5.
dec 05 23:56:36 sjisjka systemd[1]: dev-sda5.swap: Unit entered failed state.
dec 05 23:56:36 sjisjka systemd-udevd[7031]: failed to execute '/lib/udev/socket:@/org/freedesktop/hal/udev_event' 'socket:@/org/freedesktop/hal/udev_event': No such file or directory
dec 05 23:56:36 sjisjka systemd-udevd[7029]: Process 'socket:@/org/freedesktop/hal/udev_event' failed with exit code 2.
dec 06 00:25:03 sjisjka systemd[1]: poweroff.target: Job poweroff.target/start timed out.
dec 06 00:25:03 sjisjka systemd[1]: Timed out starting Power-Off.
dec 06 00:25:03 sjisjka systemd[1]: poweroff.target: Job poweroff.target/start failed with result 'timeout'.
dec 06 00:25:03 sjisjka systemd[1]: Forcibly powering off as result of failure.
dec 06 00:25:03 sjisjka systemd[1]: Shutting down.
dec 06 00:25:03 sjisjka systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
dec 06 00:25:03 sjisjka systemd-journald[298]: Journal stopped
```

The computer is a 2008 Dell with Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU, E7300  @ 2.66GHz.  It has 4 GB RAM (4×1GB) and a recent 448 GB SSD disk.

What process or component is responsible for sending the "switch off" command after the OS has closed all services (or claims to have done so)?  How might I go in debugging that this is apparently not working correctly?  What might cause this, and how do I resolve it?  At the time of writing, there are [only 5 results on Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Timed+out+starting+Power-Off%22) for "Timed out starting Power-Off".  The most promising result is [a ubuntu bug report](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/642167) with the same symptoms, but that case appears related to `cpufreqd` messages that I don't have.  There is also a [German language Linux Mint thread](https://www.linuxmintusers.de/index.php?topic=41995.0) with different symptoms and no conclusions, and a [Redhad bug description](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1214466) where it is related to NFS, which I'm not using either.  The other results are raw logs without context that don't help me any further.

Comment: I wonder if poking around journalctl would help work out what it is - probably run it right after boot and tail it with an appropriate value.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek `journalctl` has certainly given me some more leads (thanks!) and I have substantially edited the question.  I can't find a solution yet, though!

Comment: I need to go now, but [this ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1464917) seems rather promising (it also refers to askubuntu posts I haven't found yet), I will investigate that lead now.